# Doctrine Setting up the Commandline Tool. You are missing a "cli-config.php"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

There is a section in Doctrine documentation about [Setting up the Commandline Tool](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#setting-up-the-commandline-tool)

> You need to register your applications EntityManager to the console
>   tool to make use of the tasks by creating a cli-config.php

So in my bootstrap I've got:

```
// core/Cms.php
private function __construct() {

    $loader = require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
    AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

    $paths = array(ENTITY_DIR);
    $isDevMode = false;

    $dbParams = array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host'     => DB_SERVER,
        'port'     => DB_PORT,          
        'user'     => DB_USER,
        'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
        'dbname'   => DB_NAME,
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
    );

    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
    $config->setProxyDir(CLASS_DIR . '/Proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Application\Classes\Proxies');      
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory::AUTOGENERATE_FILE_NOT_EXISTS);
    $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

    $platform = $entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
    $platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');       

    self::$entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

and in same project directory core/cli-config.php:

```
// core/cli-config.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
require(SYS_DIR . '/core/Cms.php'); // my bootstrap      
Cms::initialize();
$entityManager = Cms::$entityManager;
return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Then command `php vendor/bin/doctrine --help` display:

> You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in
>   your project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working.

Answer (score -1):

working with:
`vendor/bin/doctrine --help`

instead of:
`php vendor/bin/doctrine --help`